# Why the orthogonal projection $Pu$ is a positive operator if $U$ is a subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

To prove it, we need to prove that $Pu$ is both self-adjoint and $<Puv,v>\ge 0$ for all $v∈V$. It is obvious that $<Puv,v>\ge0$, but why is it self-adjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-adjoint is equivalent to the existence of an orthonormal basis $B$, such that the matrix with respect to $B$ is symmetric (With respect to an orthonormal basis, taking the adjoint operator is the same as taking the transpose of the matrix).

Take an orthonormal basis of $U$ and an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$. Together, they form an orthonormal basis of $V$ and the matrix with respect to this basis is given by the symmetric matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}I_r & 0 \\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$, where $I_r$ is the $r \times r$-unit matrix. (r is the dimension of $U$)

As an alternative, you can just test the equality

$$\langle Px,y \rangle = \langle x,Py \rangle$$

when $x,y$ run through the orthonormal basis above.

Comment: I thought self-adjoint is equivalent to the existence of an orthonormal basis B consisting of eigenvectors of T only when V is a Real Vector Space?(by Real Spectral Theorem). Also, why does it necessarily have the symmetric matrix with r.p.t. the orthonormal basis of U and the orthonormal basis of U^⊥? Could you please tell me related definitions and theorems? I'm sorry I have not learnt about it. For the alternative part, I understand it now, thanks.

Comment: For the complex case, you can just replace 'symmetric' with 'hermitian'. The matrix above is both symmetric and hermitian (since its entries are real).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense to me. Also, why was the matrix like the one you mentioned, not the upper triangular matrix?

Answer (score 1):

In order to prove that $P$ is self-adjoint (without selecting a basis), we should prove that for any vectors $x,y$:
$$
\langle Px,y \rangle = \langle x,Py \rangle
$$
where the brackets denote the inner product (that is, the "dot-product").  Note that each vector can be written as the sum of perpendicular components, with one in $U$. We can write
$$
\langle Px,y\rangle = \\
\langle P(x^{||}+x^\perp),y^{||} + y^\perp \rangle = \\
\langle x^{||},y^{||} + y^\perp \rangle = \\
\langle x^{||},y^{||} \rangle + 
\langle x^{||},y^\perp \rangle =\\ 
\langle x^{||},y^{||} \rangle + 
0 = \\
\langle x^{||},y^{||} \rangle + 
\langle x^{\perp}, y^{||} \rangle = \\
\langle x^{||}+x^{\perp},y^{||} \rangle = \\
\langle x,Py \rangle
$$

Comment: I just made it myself. Still, a lot of thanks!

Comment: Also sorry I can only pick one answer and MooS answered it earlier.